# unable to start pm2 using flask

Tags: flask, pm2

As per the link(https://technopy.com/deploying-a-flask-application-in-production-nginx-gunicorn-and-pm2-html-2/) i followed all the steps to configure the pm2 setup but the server is nor starting up.
The following is the screenshot of the message encountered.

[image]

Once i type the command **pm2 list** there is no process started.

the Error message is:

```
2018-07-23T07:23:29.818Z] PM2 log: ===============================================================================
[2018-07-23T07:23:29.818Z] PM2 error: [PM2] Resurrecting PM2
Be sure to have the latest version by doing npm install pm2@latest -g before doing this procedure.
[PM2] Saving current process list...
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/pidusage/lib/procfile.js:26
buf = Buffer.alloc(SIZE)
^
TypeError: Buffer.alloc is not a function
at readUntilEnd (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/pidusage/lib/procfile.js:26:18)
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/pidusage/lib/procfile.js:67:5
at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:82:15)
```

pls suggest the way forward

i tried by  **pm2 kill** still it is not working out

FYI:

nodejs version: 4.2.6

pm2 3.0.0

npm 6.1.0

Answer (score 0):

Use the below commands:

$ export FLASK_APP=hello.py

$ pm2 start "flask run"

FYI:

Buffer.alloc requires Node v4.5.0

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of pidusage (dependency of pm2) is broken with the error (Buffer.alloc) you are experiencing.  This is a known issue:
https://github.com/soyuka/pidusage/issues/73

You might be able to do a temp fix until the official fix is pushed:

`-var Buffer = require('safe-buffer')
+var Buffer = require('safe-buffer').Buffer`

ie, just add .Buffer at the end.

Credit for this fix goes to user 'watson' from the link above.

Comment: Revert to version pm2@2.10.4.  This fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
pm2 start "FLASK_ENV=production FLASK_APP=my_code/app.py  flask run -h 0.0.0.0 -p 5001 --with-threads"
```